# How to set height and width of an image using Bootstrap 4 only no custom css?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to set height and width of an image using bootstrap classes only.
then I have to set a custom background color with a specific color code and set a font family for the text.

Is it possible to do this all using Bootstrap 4 classes? If yes then give me the solution.

Comment: You are expected to post your current `code` effort within your question because otherwise, you are unlikely to get any answers. (just the way it works here)

Comment: width you can set using their grid system, don't think bootstrap deals with setting height

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it only using bootstarp.The bootstrap based on the responsive. So height and witdth automatically generate with col-device-* .So for this case you must use CSS...Add ID for bootstrap row and then you can apply all CSS rule for this row....

Comment: and what about setting font family through bootstrap?

Comment: also you need to write a css for this.. Bootstrap contains only responsive design and some specific features only(ex:modal,buttons,form controls etc.)... It dont have styles.. You need to call it by using css...